# the _id of the nested docs changes every time it is requested mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i have materials schema

```
const materialSchema = new Schema<IMaterial>({
  content: [{ stage: Number, content: [{ type: String }], isCompleted: Boolean }],
  technology: [{ type: String }],
});

const MaterialModel = model<IMaterial>('materials', materialSchema);
```

and when i try to request one material:

```
MaterialModel.find(_id: requstedId)
```

each time when i do request to my material i get a new _id in my content

```
[
    {
        "_id": "61d74390cd86824b2d377178",
        "content": [
            {
                "_id": "61d749e9fdac91ca1339047b",
                "stage": 1,
                "content": [
                    "https://www.youtube.com/watch"
                ],
                "isCompleted": false
            },
            {
                "_id": "61d749e9fdac91ca1339047c",
                "stage": 2,
                "content": [
                    "https://www.youtube.com/watch"
                ],
                "isCompleted": false
            },
            {
                "_id": "61d749e9fdac91ca1339047d",
                "stage": 3,
                "content": [
                    "https://www.youtube.com/watch"
                ],
                "isCompleted": false
            }
        ],
        "technology": [
            "java"
        ]
    }
]
```

how to make permanent "_id" of nested document?

Comment: i am not sure what is the problem, but MongoDB(driver or the database) auto generates `_id` if you don't provide one on insert or upsert time,and its based on time and other parameters, if you want the documents to have a specific `_id` you have to manually provide a unique value for it

Comment: How is the `_id` of the nested document set?

Comment: @Joe i don't point ```_id``` in schema so ```_id``` is added automatically

Comment: MongoDB doesn't automatically set an _id field in a sub document, any idea what might be setting it?